# jQuery: Determine if jQuery object is root html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, document

Let's say I'm writing a jQuery extension method. This method should climb the ancestor tree of an element until it reaches the document's root `<html>` tag, at which point it should stop. I've implemented this as shown here:

```
$.fn.foo = function() {

    var $foo = this;

    while($foo[0] !== $(document).children()[0]) {
        // do stuff with $foo
        $foo = $foo.parent();
    }

    // do stuff

};
```

My question is: is there a better way than `$foo[0] !== $(document).children()[0]` to know whether I've reached the root `<html>` tag?

Comment: should the plugin do stuff with the `<html>` element as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$foo.is('html')
```

You seem to be reimplementing [parents()](http://api.jquery.com/parents/), though.

Answer (score 3):

Don't compare against the first child, just see if a parent is returned:

```
var $foo = $(this);

while($foo.parent().length > 0) {
    // do stuff with $foo
    $foo = $foo.parent();
}
```

Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BLZCR/).

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
$.fn.foo = function() {

    var $foo = this;

    while($foo[0].tagName != 'HTML') {
        // do stuff with $foo
        $foo = $foo.parent();
    }

    // do stuff

};
```

Alternatively, if you don't actually need to traverse up, but only want to do things to all ancestors of a given node, you could use .parents() like so:

```
$.fn.foo = function() {

    var $foo = this;

    $foo.parents().andSelf().each(function() {
        // do stuff with $foo
    });

    // do stuff

};
```

Answer (score 1):

This should stop at `HTML`.

```
​$foo.parents().andSelf().each(function() {
    // do something
    console.log(this.nodeName);
});​​​
```

Or if you're running the same jQuery method(s) against each node, do this:

```
$foo.parents().andSelf().someJQueryMethod();
```

- http://api.jquery.com/parents/
- http://api.jquery.com/andself/